# How to check that two RDF graphs have the same content?

Tags: c, xml-serialization, xml-parsing, rdf, rdflib

I'm writing a C library that parses and serializes domain-specific data as RDF/XML. After I parse a file and write it back out again I'd like to be able to check that the content hasn't changed.

I could parse everything again, write it out as NTriples, and compare the two Ntriples files line-by-line but there must be a better way right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use an hash function (such as MD5 or SHA1) but RDF/XML as well as other RDF serialization formats can be **serialized in different ways** all corresponding to the **same RDF graph**.

Moreover, **blank nodes** labels if you use Turtle or N-Triples formats will be different each time. For this reasons, an hash function might not be the best option.

[Graph isomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem) is an 'interesting' problem. ;-)

It's not written in C, but you could try to decipher what Apache Jena does in [GraphMatcher.java](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-core/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/graph/impl/GraphMatcher.java).

As alternative, as you said, if you do not have blank nodes, you can serialize data out in N-Triples, sort and compare those files or have your own sorted data structure and use that instead, avoiding the serialization step.

Comment: Well this looks entirely too hard for the problem at hand. :) But it's good to know I wasn't missing something obvious. Since I know in my case there won't be blank nodes I'll try comparing triple-for-triple.

Comment: If you do not have blank nodes, you can use a data structure which sorts your triples or, as you said N-Triples, and compare that. With no blank nodes an hash function over your triples in sorted order would do as well.

Answer (score -3):

You can calculate a strong hash (e.g., MD5 or SHA1) of both files. The hashes will match if the files are equal byte for byte.